# Spring MVC Restful service response

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Any idea why I get a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" when I set

```
Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
```

I can see that this has been set correctly in the response body?

```
curl -v http://my_host/api/v1/user/99999999
```

***HTTP/1.1 200 OK***

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE

....

{"statusType":"NOT_FOUND","entity":"Unable to retrieve product with id:99999999","entityType":"java.lang.String","status":404,"metadata":{}}

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response getProduct(@PathVariable String id) {

    Product product = null; //productService.getProduct(id);
    if (product == null) {
        // I KNOW I GET HERE !!!
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Unable to retrieve product with id:"+id). build();
    }

    // AS EXPECTED I DO NOT GET HERE
    Map<String, Object> json = productRenderer.renderProduct(....);
    return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type("application/json").build();
}
```

BTW am using Spring version 3.2.10

Comment: Not sure if you can set 404 with in the controller level. Have you tried some other status codes to see if it works?

Comment: @NMK I've just tried with Response.Status.FORBIDDEN & Response.Status.CONFLICT but to no avail. Once more the body is correct but the HTTP/1.1 is 200.

Answer (score 2):

Try returning Spring's `ResponseEntity` instead. It works for me and sets the correct response status:

For example:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

or with body:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
```

You can also use builder pattern as you do with `Response` in your question (following example is from ResponseEntity's JavaDoc:

```
return ResponseEntity
        .created(location)
        .header("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue")
        .body("Hello World");
```

More details can be found in the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Comment: I have just tried with ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) but as before the HTTP/1.1 is 200.

Comment: I just tried this solution on a simple Spring Boot app and it worked correctly. Could you perhaps provide some more information about your project which might help determine where else the problem could be? Also could you try updating to Spring 4 to see if that makes any difference if that's a possiblity?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Update to Spring 4 is not an option :(. My project detials: Spring 3.2.10, Java 1.7; 
javax.ws.rs.core.Response jersey-core-1.17.1.jar. 

using SaopUI 

RAW:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 11:22:12 GMT
{"statusType":"NOT_FOUND","entity":"Unable to retrieve product","entityType":"java.lang.String","status":404,"metadata":{}}

Comment: OK I just tried the ResponseEntity solution on a sample app using Spring 3.2.10 and it still works. Maybe something is overriding your response status codes? But to be honest I'm running out of ideas as to what could be causing this. Perhaps somebody else will have more lock diagnosing this problem. Sorry I was not much help

Comment: Did you remove @ResponseBody when using ResponseEntity?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was due to the fact that the Response object was been rendered as a JSON due to the setting of the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter bean. Hence the HTTP response was always going to be 200 and the response body contained the JSON representation of `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`.

```
<bean id="..." class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
```

To get around the problem I throw a custom exception with `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus` annotation :

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ProductNotFoundException extends Exception {
    ... 
}
```

Hence my original method now looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response getProduct(@PathVariable String id) throws ProductNotFoundException {
    ...
}
```